# Best practices for bilingual CiviEvents pages with price sets?

Tags: civievent, i18n, translation, multilingual, l10n

still on Drupal and Civi 5.x.

What is the best practice for offering a Civi Event in English and Spanish? We would want the price set to be translated, the event description, the email, confirmation pages, etc.

Is cloning the best option? Would we need to duplicate the custom fields and profiles in use, or use string translation?